# Check if line matches regex

Tags: regex, vb.net, io

I have a file that has been generated by a server - I have no control over how this file is generated or formatted. I need to check each line begins with a string of set length (in this case 21 numerical chars). If a line doesn't match that condition, I need to join it to the previous line and, after reading and correcting the whole file, save it. I am doing this for a lot of files in a directory.

So far I have:

```
       Dim rgx As New Regex("^[0-9]{21}$")

        Dim linesList As New List(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines(finfo.FullName))

        If linesList(0).Contains("BlackBerry Messenger") Then
            linesList.RemoveAt(0)
            For i As Integer = 0 To linesList.Count
                  If Not rgx.IsMatch(i.ToString) Then
                        linesList.Concat(linesList(i-1))
                 End If

            Next
        End If
        File.WriteAllLines(finfo.FullName, linesList.ToArray())[code]
```

There's a for statement before and after that code block to loop over all files in the source directory, which works fine.

Hope this isn't too bad to read :/

Comment: You need to check if each line _begins_ with 21 digits but you anchor your regex to the end -- why?

Comment: Nope, that "$" wasn't supposed to be there ...long night! Thank you. Still a little stuck with the rest.

Comment: On `rgx.IsMatch(i.ToString)`, it won't ever match, because `i` is the loop variable, and `Integer`. I'm assuming you meant `rgx.IsMatch(linesList(i))`?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. While the loop works as rgx.IsMatch(linesList(i)) , I can't seem to manage the rest yet.

Comment: You should post a sample of your data file. Should all lines be of 21 numeric chars or do you have some lines that doesn't match at all and not because they are splitted in two consecutive lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't think your solution was any good, you were failing on concatenating the lines. Here's a different approach:

```
Dim rgx As New Regex("^[0-9]{21}")
Dim linesList As New List(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines(finfo.FullName))

' We will create a new list to store the new lines data
Dim newLinesList As New List(Of String)()

If linesList(0).Contains("BlackBerry Messenger") Then
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim newLine As String
    While i < linesList.Count
        newLine = linesList(i)
        i += 1

        ' Keep going until the "real" line is over
        While i < linesList.Count AndAlso Not rgx.IsMatch(linesList(i))
            newLine += linesList(i)
            i += 1
        End While

        newLinesList.Add(newLine)
    End While
End If

File.WriteAllLines(finfo.FullName, newLinesList.ToArray())
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, and I do see where I was going COMPLETELY wrong...thank you!